# Geocoding fail in valid request PHP

Tags: php, google-maps

I try to convert address to latitude and longitude. I have over 900 objects in database and 229 objects returns ZERO_RESULT or INVALID_REQUEST in valid request (when i use web browser everything is all right). I use UTF-8 coding.

```
$address= utf8_encode($street.$city);
$urlreq= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$address."&sensor=true";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($urlreq) or die("url not loading");
```

$address: ?apino Kartuskie 
$urlreq: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=?apino Kartuskie&sensor=true 
$xml->status: ZERO_RESULTS

Thank you for help

Comment: Put in a valid address? You're probably not giving it enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You're not encoding the special characters properly. If you try http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=%C5%81apino+Kartuskie&sensor=true that works fine.

Notice the first character. Make sure to run `url_encode` on your address before sending it to google.